# Java Algorithm time measure

Tags: java, algorithm

My problem is that when i try to get an accurate measurement of my algorithms execution time, the result differ to much once the first set of tests have been done.

I have 7 text files with Integers, each text file have a power of two elements.

> 2<sup>4</sup> = 16        
>   2<sup>8</sup> = 256       
>   2<sup>12</sup> = 4096     
>   2<sup>16</sup> = 65536    
>   2<sup>20</sup> = 1048576  
>   2<sup>22</sup> = 4194304  
>   2<sup>24</sup> = 16777216

I am running these tests X number of times to get the execution time.
A test case is considered executing all the above tests once. And i am doing this several times without changing the text files data.

To measure my algorithm execution time, im using System.nanoTime();

```
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        (Algorithm)
        long elapsedNanoTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
```

However, the results, shows a major drop for the starting tests 16 and 256 after the first test case have been executed.

> Test case, iteration 1: 
>   16 elements takes 325336n  
>   256 elements takes 414861n 
>   4096 elements takes 2061728n 
>   65536 elements takes 21111426n 
>   1048576 elements takes 326898979n 
>   4194304 elements takes 1487154649n
>   16777216 elements takes 6700800203n
>
> Test case, iteration 2: 
>   16 elements takes 2925n
>   256 elements takes 36864n
>   4096 elements takes 885603n 
>   65536 elements takes 15839933n 
>   1048576 elements takes 332000198n 
>   4194304 elements takes 1484967410n 
>   16777216 elements takes 6695675287n
>
> Test case, iteration 3: 
>   16 elements takes 2926n 
>   256 elements takes 35985n
>   4096 elements takes 679635n
>   65536 elements takes 15462227n
>   1048576 elements takes 328179551n
>   4194304 elements takes 1483733064n
>   16777216 elements takes 6704160641n

And if i run each test case separately, "Compiling" the program to do only 7 tests, the results all comes out like the above iteration 1.

So do anyone have some insight as to why  the execution time differ from the first test case and the others? Does it have to do with the initialization of the program or that the memory already have the allocated data somewhere? Because as of now, i'm not sure which execution time data is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google "java virtual machine warm up"

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/572670)

Comment: I/O is super expensive - are you reading in each text file one time in each iteration when programing it to do 7 tests, or are you only reading in the files once?

Comment: Run each test 1000 times, throw away too large results, compute an avg.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, now i know what to look for. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarking is hard, and you've stumbled upon one of the more common troublesome cases; the [JIT compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation).  The JVM is actually responsible for compiling some of the code you run *as its running*, in order to optimize the bytecode further than the compiler itself can hope to do.

Describing how to ensure your benchmarks are accurate is beyond what can fit in an answer (but there are [many resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20benchmark%20best%20practices)) but for this particular issue what you want to do is run your benchmark multiple times (in the same JVM) and discard the first few runs as noise.  Once the benchmark has been run a couple of times the JIT will have had a chance to optimize your code for you, and *likely* won't make more optimizations in successive runs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) as a framework for your micro benchmark.  As pointed out out in @dimo414's answer, benchmarking is hard on the JVM.